# Generates the power set of the set without using pre-defined library?

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to generate the power set of the list,without using any library.
For example, given the `set {1, 2, 3},` it should return `{{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}`

**Note: We can use list also for it.**

I have implemented the code , but it is not dynamic , it is for the specific length . How can I make it dynamic.

**Code:**

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]

first_list = []
second_list = [[]]
final_list = []

for iterate in my_list:
    second_list.append([iterate])
    
for outer_loop in my_list:
    for inner_loop in my_list:
        if outer_loop!=inner_loop:
            first_list.append([outer_loop, inner_loop])
            
result = (second_list + first_list)

for iterated in result:
    if sorted(iterated) not in final_list:
        final_list.append(iterated)
final_list + [my_list]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
def get_powerset(s):
    x = len(s)
    subsets = []
    for i in range(1 << x):
        subsets.append([s[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))])

    return subsets

lists = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
for num_list in lists:
    print(get_powerset(num_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], [0], [1], [0, 1], [2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [3], [0, 3], [1, 3], [0, 1, 3], [2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Sabil's answer, a recursive approach:

```py
def get_powerset(s):
    if len(s) == 0: 
        return []
    if len(s) == 1: 
        return [s] 
    without_s0 = get_powerset(s[1:])
    with_s0 = [subs + [s[0]] for subs in without_s0]
    return with_s0 + without_s0
```

This solution assumes a **item** method, but that can be easily relaxed.